# Phone bricked? Stuck in boot (can't access ADB)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, boot-loop, unbricking, motorola-moto-g3

Unfortunately my Moto G XT1543 is stuck in the boot. PWR + VOL DWN does not work, and adb returns the following:

> adb reboot bootloader
>
> - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
> - daemon started successfully
> - error: device '(null)' not found

The official motorola drivers can't recognize the device. I'm completely stuck. Any advise?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that PWR + VOL DWN wasn't working, I apologize if I can't provide a more accurate answer, but PWR + VOL DWN finally worked and I was able to connect with adb once again.

Comment: Oh. Well that's good, eh? A happy ending :) just remember to mark this as an answer Tomorrow.